# Installed ARR, cannot find Application Request Routing Cache icon

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, arr

I'm following this [tutorial on installing ARR](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr). I've installed ARR using Web PI in Windows 2008 R2.

The second step in the tutorial is:

> Double click the “Application Request Routing Cache” icon

Under the server node, I cannot find this icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create reverse proxies by clicking on **Site**, **URL Rewrite**, **Add Rule** and **Reverse Proxy**.

Answer (score 1):

1) Remove all components of the ISS through ccleaner or standard means of windows.
2) Clean cache and regedit (optional but desirable)
3) Re-install the components that you need to manually downloading them from the microsoft site (for ARR is the following installation sequence: -WebDeployversion 2.0 (without him was not installed WebFarmFrameworkversion 2.2)

- WebPlatformInstaller 3.0 (without him was not installed WebFarmFrameworkversion 2.2)
- WebFarmFrameworkversion 2.2 (version 1.1 on R2 does not want to work)
- External Cache version 1.0
- URL Rewrite version 2.0
- ARR Version 3.0)

4) Restart the ISS manager

Answer (score 0):

I closed and reopened IIS and the icon appeared after that.